# Which is faster, Loading assets from a big package or from many files spread across the filesystem?

Tags: performance, io, filesystems, storage

Many applications, mostly video-games (mainly ones with constant content streaming), takes the approach of having a single big package file containing many of the game assets, that's [arguably] used for security-and space efficiency reasons, but perhaps there's a performance reason?

Given an application that loads 3+ assets file on each 5 seconds using asynchronous I/O in a secondary streaming thread, would it be technically faster if the I/O was being performed on a single big file by seeking and reading to the various offsets of the assets when necessary or to read each file separately spread across the operating system file system?

There would probably be a different across HDDs, SDDs and other factors, what are those?

Assume the files aren't fragmented (i.e. reserved space for those was applied during installation before effectively writing the content), but specifying the affects on fragmentation on the result would be interesting too.

The files spread on the filesystem approach seems interesting for quick production and modding support, but if there's a performance penalty, care should be taken.

This question is purely theoretical and curiosity at this point.

Comment: Its more appropriate to post  this question in http://programmers.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @Ram if this were asked on Programmers, we would close it and leave a comment asking "what happened when you profiled your code?" The answer relies on implementation-specific factors such as file system, whether running on a HDD or SSD, OS, etc. In other words, closed as "too broad." Also please read: **[What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/22815)**.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a file handle/descriptor requires security validation and file system metadata operations. So is arguably that the many small file operations will be slower than one operation one one big file. Whether is a *measurable* difference in the specific context of your code, that remains to be demonstrated.

BTW True asynchronous IO should no require 'secondary' threads. You likely describe synchronous IO performed on a different thread, a completely different beast.

Achieving high throughput IO is very platform specific. To illustrate, for Windows specific read [Designing Applications for High Performance - Part 1](http://blogs.technet.com/b/winserverperformance/archive/2008/04/25/designing-applications-for-high-performance-part-1.aspx), [Part 2](http://blogs.technet.com/b/winserverperformance/archive/2008/05/21/designing-applications-for-high-performance-part-ii.aspx) and [Part 3](http://blogs.technet.com/winserverperformance/archive/2008/06/26/designing-applications-for-high-performance-part-iii.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Opening a file requires string processing to verify the file name, finding the directory the block references are in and then seeking to the first block of the file to start reading.

The directory lookup can be cached but all the rest has a cost per file.

Also having one big file lets the OS know that it will be accessed in one go and read the next blocks of the file while you are processing the data; however if you only read some assets then this read-ahead will possibly read unnecessary blocks.

A better solution would be a hybrid approach: collect assets that are often loaded together in buckets and have a database that say per level which asset buckets need to be read.

You can also duplicate the data across several buckets; in extreme each level has a single bucket with all the assets that level needs. This takes up more space but will net you the greatest speedup as you only need to dump 1 file into memory.

[This presentation](https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/deplinenoise-misc/LoadingImperfectDataFinal.pdf) talks about how you can create a good distribution of seeks (files in this context) vs. amount of assets within a storage budget.

When creating a game for PC you can let the use decide on install which side of the coin he wants, the quick loading of 1 file per level or the space saving of each asset stored only once.